# Is there a way to copy all constraints from one element to another?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

Situation: I have an image on my storyboard that has a lot of other elements using it for relative positioning (constraints). I need to replace this image with a view that will have other content, without messing with the layout. Thus, I want to be able to copy all the constraints that currently affect the image, and make it affect the new view instead.

Is this possible? I tried to go through it manually by making new constraints for this view according to the constraints that affected the image, but the layout was still messed up when all was set and done. I'm guessing I missed a constraint somewhere and it's throwing off the layout tool.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you add an view above that image, and make it having the leading/trailing/top/bottom equals to its superview (the imageview)?

Comment: What is this "new view"? Does it have the same intrinsic content size as the old image? You can't just copy everything over, but change one of the images to something general view. That is not going to work in general, which is why there is no such feature. You can copy everything *and keep everything the same*, but as soon as you start changing things, *you* need to think about the layout.

Comment: It is ***very difficult*** to answer questions in the abstract. Edit your question and provide more detail -- include screen-caps or illustrations if that helps. We need to know, for example, what you mean by *"a lot of other elements using it for relative positioning"*.